# Python on multiprocessor machines: multiprocessing or a non-GIL interpreter

Tags: python, multiprocessing

This is more a style question.  For CPU bound processes that really benefit for having multiple cores, do you typically use the multiprocessing module or use threads with an interpreter that doesn't have the GIL?  I've used the multiprocessing library only lightly, but also have no experience with anything besides CPython.  I'm curious what the preferred approach is and if it is to use a different interpreter, which one.

Comment: What is your workload like? From a "style" perspective (which apparently *is* very important to python programmmers), I don't think many python advocates would prefer a non-GIL interpreter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really see a "style" argument to be made here, either way -- both `multiprocessing` in CPython 2.6, and `threading` in (e.g.) the current versions of Jython and IronPython, let you code in extremely similar ways (and styles;-).  So, I'd choose on the basis of very "hard-nosed" considerations -- what is performance like with each choice (if I'm *so* CPU-bound as to benefit from multiple cores, then performance is *obviously* of paramount importance), could I use with serious benefit any library that's CPython-only (like `numpy`) or maybe something else that's JVM- or .NET- only, and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Parallel Python ([www.parallelpython.com](http://www.parallelpython.com)) -- I've used to to nicely split up work among the processors on my quad-core box.  It even supports clusters!

Comment: Ideally you would do some benchmarking to determine how many Python processes per CPU can be handled without degrading performance. I would start with three Python processes per core and work upwards.